# Fluid Grid - How do I use them in Responsive Web Design?

Tags: css, grid, responsive-design, media-queries, fluid

Please forgive me, but can somebody please explain to me the purpose of the Fluid Grid, as featured on cssgrid, for example. By grid, I refer to those columns, some are 9, others 12, others 24 columns...

1). Is the grid used as a background, or stencil, for the correct sizing and positioning of DIVS?

2). Is it essential that a fluid grid (9, 12, 24 columns) is used in designing for a Responsive website, or can I just use CSS3 and media queries to define break points?

3). What's the difference between the number of columns, and why would I use 9, instead of 24 columns, for example. Is a higher column count better for more content?

4). Why are there so many Fluid Grid generators available? Is it because each one is better or different in some way?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1). Is the grid used as a background, or stencil, for the correct sizing and positioning of DIVS?

Yes, that's more or less it. You could picture the grid as an invisible stencil to help with the sizing and positioning of the divs. Since you are talking responsive design, the widths of the grid columns will vary, depending on the width of the veiwer's browser window.

> 2). Is it essential that a fluid grid (9, 12, 24 columns) is used in designing for a Responsive website, or can I just use CSS3 and media queries to define break points?

Grids are intended to simplify your life, but there's nothing to stop you rolling your own solution, or mixing custom CSS styles with an off-the-shelf fluid grid framework

> 3). What's the difference between the number of columns, and why would I use 9, instead of 24 columns, for example. Is a higher column count better for more content?

You can picture that for a given window width, more columns = narrower columns. You might find that more columns gives you better control for a given page layout, just depends on the specific of your project. In practice, more columns will actually give you less space for content because of the gutter or spacing between each grid column. If you are thinking resoponsive design including mobile, then at some point most grid frameworks start displaying the columns as a vertical stack, ie:
1-2-3
becomes
1
2
3

Dividing a hand-held screen into 9 vertical columns isn't going to be very usable

> 4). Why are there so many Fluid Grid generators available? Is it because each one is better or different in some way?

Partly personal preference, you may like one option over another, and partly different features. Some frameworks like [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com) or [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) come with a lot of extra CSS styling as well as additional javascript resources that you may wish to use.

Have fun ... it's an interesting time for web design!

Answer (score 1):

Know it deeply with ETHAN MARCOTTE -  [Alist Apart on RWD.](http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design)